# Why the schema of user methods does not working

Tags: node.js, methods, mongodb-schema

When I update the password it is done. But the method used in the schema is not work.

```
// route file
route.put("/update-password", auth_middleware, update_password);

// userController file
const update_password = asyncHandler(async (request, response) => {
    try {
        const { id } = request.user;
        const { password } = request.body;
        validateMongodbId(id);
        const findUser = await user_model.findById(id);
        createPasswordResetToken()
        if (password) {
            findUser.password = password;
            const updateUser = await findUser.save();
            response.json(updateUser);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(`Errorrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr: ${err}`)
    }
})

// This is all the code in the schema file
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { genSaltSync, hashSync, compareSync } = require("bcrypt");
const crypto = require('crypto');
// Schema
const schema_user = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    mobile: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    block: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      default: "user",
    },
    cart: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    },
    address: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Address" }],
    wishlist: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Product" }],
    refreshToken: {
      type: String,
    },
    passwordChangedAt: {type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Date},
    passwordResetToken: {type: String},
    passwordResetExpires: {type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Date},
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

// Hashing Password
schema_user.pre("save", function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) next();
  const salt = genSaltSync();
  this.password = hashSync(this.password, salt);
  next();
});

// comper password
function comparePassword(raw, hash) {
  return compareSync(raw, hash);
}


schema_user.methods.createPasswordResetToken = async function () {
  try {
    const resteToken = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex");
    this.passwordResetToken = crypto
      .createHash("sha256")
      .update(resteToken)
      .digest("hex");
    this.passwordResetExpires = Date.now() + 10 * 60 * 1000; // 10 دقائق
    
    console.log(this.passwordResetToken);
    console.log(resteToken);

    return resteToken;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(`Errorrrrrrrrrr: ${err}`)
  }
}

// Model
const user_model = mongoose.model("User_Authenticat", schema_user);
module.exports = {
  user_model,
  comparePassword,
  createPasswordResetToken,
};
```

Create a path that enables the user to update the password. And everything was fine, but the problem with this method `createPasswordResetToken` in the scheme does not work at all.

I did expect these properties to be saved
`passwordChangedAt: Date, passwordResetToken: String, passwordResetExpires: Date,`
in the database, But this did not happen.

What do I do to make this method createPasswordResetToken work and save these fields
passwordChangedAt
passwordResetToken
passwordResetExpires in the database when the user updates the password

Comment: Can you share the code of the entire model instead of the screenshot and highlight which lines are not working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

To fix this issue and ensure that the ***createPasswordResetToken*** method is executed when you update the password, you need to call the method on the specific user instance instead of calling it as a standalone function.

Here's how you can modify your **update_password** route handler to make it work:

```
const update_password = asyncHandler(async (request, response) => {
try {
const { id } = request.user;
const { password } = request.body;
validateMongodbId(id);
const findUser = await user_model.findById(id);

if (password) {
  findUser.password = password;
  const resetToken = findUser.createPasswordResetToken(); // Call the method on the user instance
  await findUser.save(); // Save the updated password and the generated reset token
  response.json({ message: 'Password updated successfully', resetToken });
 }
 } catch (err) {
throw new Error(`Errorrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr: ${err}`);
}
});
```

In the updated code, we call the **createPasswordResetToken** method on the **findUser** instance, and then we save the user object to the database with the updated password and the generated reset token.